# how to pivot question in MS Word into excel cells?

Tags: excel, ms-word, pivot

in my word file i have questions in this format:

```
'Question text - how to do this'?

•    A.option1
•    B.option2
•    C.option3
•    D.option4

Explanation
```

I need to insert it into excel , need to pivot like this:

> question text option1 option2 option3  explanation

How to do it automatically?

Comment: Perhaps easier via a text editor to replace the line return etc with a , and then parse it in?

Comment: @SolarMike could u show please with python code?

Comment: I suggested “via a text editor” as some are really good at converting line returns etc. I use one ss it preps csv files I have to convert.

Comment: And if you want python code it might be a good idea to tag “python”....

Comment: It sounds like a job for **PowerQuery** (a built-in function in Excel 2013 or later versions). You can load the data from the word document and use pivot related functions to achieve the desired outcome. How about you give it a go and then post a more specific question about Power Query then someone, if not me, can help you out?